# How to implement custom keyboard for UITextFields in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield

[image: Image Link]

how to implement a custom keyboard for `UITextFields` in iOS like the above image

Actually i'm tried like that

```
- (IBAction)button2ABC:(id)sender
{
    keypadValue=@"2";
    if ([textFields_tag isEqualToString:@"one"]){
        pswdTxt1.text=keypadValue;
        pswdTxt1.text=[keypadValue  stringByAppendingString:keypadValue];
    }
    else if ([textFields_tag isEqualToString:@"two"]){
        pswdTxt2.text=keypadValue;
    }
    else if ([textFields_tag isEqualToString:@"three"]){
        pswdTxt3.text=keypadValue;
    }
    else if ([textFields_tag isEqualToString:@"four"]){
        PswdTxt4.text=keypadValue;
    }
}
```

Whenever I'm pressing the button after selecting the `UITextfield` that character is replacing not appending with previous one.